# Servo Motor and ADC Synchronization Issue in AVR C Code

Tags: c, avr, adc, servo, atmega32

I'm working on an AVR ATMega32a microcontroller-based project where I'm using a servo motor to rotate from 0 to 90 degrees while capturing ADC values at each degree of rotation. I aim to synchronize the servo motor's rotation with the ADC value capture, ensuring that I receive the corresponding ADC value for each degree of rotation before proceeding to the next degree.

Context:

Microcontroller: I'm using an AVR microcontroller, ATmega32A.
MG995 Servo Motor: The servo motor is controlled via PWM to rotate from 0 to 90 degrees.
ADC Configuration: I have configured the ADC to read values from a photodiode sensor.
Connections: The servo motor and the photodiode sensor are connected to the microcontroller.

The problem I'm facing is that the servo motor appears to rotate 90 degrees before the ADC values are transmitted for all degrees. Ideally, I expect the motor to rotate to each degree incrementally and wait for the corresponding ADC value before proceeding to the next degree.

Here's a simplified version of the relevant parts of my C code:

```
// Function to transmit a byte via UART
void UART_TxChar(char ch) {
    while (! (UCSRA & (1 << UDRE))); /* Wait for empty transmit buffer */
    UDR = ch;
}

// Function to send a string via UART
void UART_SendString(char *str) {
    unsigned char j = 0;
    while (str[j] != 0) /* Send string up to null */
    {
        UART_TxChar(str[j]);
        j++;
    }
}
...
// Function to rotate the servo to a specified degree
void RotateServo(uint16_t degree) {
    OCR1A = (degree * 125) / 9 + 175; // Calculate the OCR1A value for the specified degree
    _delay_ms(500); // Wait for the servo to reach the desired position
}

int main() {
    ...

    while (1) {
        for (int degree = 0; degree <= 90; degree++) {
            RotateServo(degree);

            // Read the ADC value from channel 0 (connected to photodiode)
            adc_value = adc_read(0);

            // Print the ADC value to the serial terminal
            sprintf(buffer, "Degree: %d, ADC Value: %d \n", degree, adc_value);
            UART_SendString(buffer);

            // Wait for a moment before moving to the next degree
            _delay_ms(1000);
        }

        _delay_ms(2000); // Wait for 2 seconds before reversing

        for (int degree = 90; degree >= 0; degree--) {
            RotateServo(degree);

            // Read the ADC value from channel 0 (connected to photodiode)
            adc_value = adc_read(0);

            // Print the ADC value to the serial terminal
            sprintf(buffer, "Degree: %d, ADC Value: %d \n", degree, adc_value);
            UART_SendString(buffer);

            // Wait for a moment before moving to the next degree
            _delay_ms(1000);
        }

        _delay_ms(1000); // Wait for 1 second before restarting the loop
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have attempted to adjust the delay between servo motor movements and ADC value captures, but this hasn't resolved the issue.

My expectation is to achieve synchronized rotation of the servo motor and the capture of ADC values, degree by degree, ensuring that the motor doesn't move to the next degree until the ADC value for the current degree is obtained.

- Is there a way to synchronize the servo motor rotation with ADC value capture for each degree?
- Are there any potential reasons for the delay in ADC value transmission?
- Are there adjustments needed in the code or hardware setup to achieve synchronization?

I would appreciate any insights, advice, or solutions that can help me address this synchronization issue. Thank you for your assistance.

Edit:
Finally I figured out the mistake

```
    // Function to rotate the servo to a specified degree
void RotateServo(uint16_t degree) {
    OCR1A = (degree * 125) / 90 + 175; // Calculate the OCR1A value for the specified degree
    _delay_ms(500); // Wait for the servo to reach the desired position
}
```

The only mistake I made was not adding 90 for the specified degree which made my motor rotate 10x speed in one turn. My bad

Thank you so much to everyone who helped me in numerous ways.

Comment: The code looks pretty good to me and I'd expect your ADC to correspond correctly to the desired servo positions.  What baud rate are you using?  Where is the source code of `UART_SendString`?  Did you calculate how long your serial messages will take to send?  Did you consider that maybe the data is not getting delayed at the microcontroller level and not that you're just using a terminal program that's slow to draw the characters on your screen?  How do you know the data is getting delayed?

Comment: @DavidGrayson
Thank you for acknowledging my efforts and providing additional details. With a baud rate of 9600 and considering the time frame for sending serial messages, it's apparent that the issue lies in the servo motor's speed, which exceeds the ADC value capture rate of one degree per data. (i.e. the servo motor rotates more than one degree while the ADC values pass per degree) This insight helps narrow down the problem, and I appreciate any further guidance on addressing this synchronization challenge.

Comment: Your latest comment just doesn't make sense.  You're delaying long enough after changing the pulse width that the servo should come to a rest before you take the ADC reading.  If not, then just delay longer.  You're in control of what position it is in for every ADC reading.  What *exactly* makes you think the data is wrong?

Comment: Your MCU has a regular SA ADC, it is super fast compared to all these delays. To quote The Friendly Manual, the maximum conversion time possible is 260us. You need to _sync_ the ADC reads in time versus the servo, which _cannot_ be done with busy-wait delays. Use single conversion and start the conversion at a known point in time after the last command to the servo. You _need_ to implement the changes with hardware timers explained in my answer, everything else is quackery and will leave you with zero control over timing.

Answer (score 1):

As things stand now, everything in your program depends on anything else. Both UART transmission and `sprintf` are very time consuming. Whereas an ADC cycle is extremely fast in comparison to all that, let alone the massive delays everywhere.

So step #1 is to convert all of this from "hobbyist hell" to an actual real-time system, which can do multiple things at the same time. That means get rid of all the evil `_delay_ms` and start using hardware peripheral timers. You should have something handling the ADC, something handling the servo and something handling the console stuff/UART and these 3 things shouldn't have tight coupling timing dependencies vs each other.

Each driver could have a callback triggering every 1ms or something, then deciding if it is time to act. Is the UART available or busy - if busy, then obviously we shouldn't sit around and twiddle thumbs in a busy-wait but leave the timer callback and let the rest of the program do meaningful stuff instead while we wait. Same with servo and ADC.

Depending on how your ADC driver works and how the ADC is set up, it might return the last value read, or it might actually busy-wait poll the ADC to finish (which would be bad too). Sometimes you want the ADC to require a manual kick to initiate each conversion, in other situations you want to use a "continuous conversion" feature to leave the ADC running and repeatedly update its data register and then you just grab the latest value. I can't say what suits your application best.

Comment: Blocking code works fine for simple applications like this.  You're asking the OP to re-engineering everything before we know what the actual problem is, which isn't likely to help.

Comment: @DavidGrayson It does not work fine or they wouldn't be asking this question. There's no re-engineering, there is either correct engineering or hobbyist quick & dirty. Professional programs as used in real-world applications avoid busy-wait delays - there hardly ever exists a situation where you can justify one.

Comment: There's no need for concurrency here so blocking code can work fine.  Step 1: move servo and delay long enough for its position to stabilize.  Step 2: take an ADC reading.   Step 3: transmit result on UART.  Step 4: go back to step 1.   The OP is already doing that so we need to understand why this didn't work before we can give a real answer.

Comment: @DavidGrayson No but there is a need for more or less exact timing here - you have to sync the servo with the ADC in a relayable manner and that ***cannot*** be done with sloppy busy-delays. I'm explaining how real-time systems are developed professionally. Of course nobody has to listen, hobbyists without quality concerns are welcome to ask questions too and remain forever a hobbyist playing with retro 1990s MCU in their free time. However, there _is_ an engineering aspect of this technical site, namely that we should advocate for using best practices and avoid against using bad practices.

Comment: There is no need for super precise timing.  The way the a typical RC servo works is that you send it a series of pulses and it attempts to go to the position corresponding to the pulse width.  So all you need to do to make this simple application work is delay long enough after changing the pulse width to ensure the servo has reached is final position before you take the ADC reading.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably has nothing to do with the ADC, but rather the code that initializes the timer you used to generate the PWM pulse, or more precisely - the lack of it.

Additionally, its unclear whether or not you are correctly converting the 0-90 number into a correct `OCR1A` value which corresponds to the servo's specs (typical servos have a period of 20ms, where the first 500-2500us are the high pulse) I see no `#define` for your CPU frequency, no code which defines output pins for the pwm outputs, you basically have no code that controls the most important part of moving the motor correctly. I suggest diving into the datasheet section for the `timer counter 1` (page 93).